# Magento Set Selected Filter In Layered Navigation

Tags: category, layered-navigation

we would like to Set a selected filter on initial page load for a category.

For example: when accessing the category, shoe_size=10 should already be selected

I read you can access the variables quite easily [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32041/magento-set-default-filter-in-layered-navigation)

**But how do I**

- pass a variable to the code? (can this be done through a custom layout update in category xml in backend)?
- But more importantly. How do I SET the shoe_size filter to value 10 in code? Is there a setFilter()?

Help appreciated

Answer (score 3):

The values for the layered nav filter are retrieved from the request ($_GET). you can try to use an observer for `controller_action_predispatch_catalog_category_view` where you check if you are on the correct category (and other conditions if you have any) and try to set a value in the request.
Something like this:

```
public function setDefaultFilter($observer) 
{
    if (your conditinos here) {
        Mage::app()->getRequest()->setParam('shoe_size', 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: That sounds great Marius'. Super. And could I pass the variables from custom layout update too? (And grab them)

Comment: Thanks a ton Marius, I was looking for this solution from a long long time